# Reading a line and assigning a default value to the variables in BASH

Tags: bash, shell

How do I read a row of data and assign them to variables while also giving them default values?

I wanted to achieve something like this, but can't get the syntax right.

```
{ 
read variable1=${variable1:=default1} variable2=${variable2:=default2} 
read variable3=${variable3:=default3} variable4=${variable4:=default4} 
} <fileList
```

Comment: Is your file delimited?  The requirement is not clear.

Comment: The file is only space and newline separated.

Comment: Are you only dealing with just 4 variables or is the number of variables unknown?

Comment: The maximum number of variables is 4 but it is possible to only get one line (i.e. only 2 variables)

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop:

```
while read -r var1 var2 dummy; do
  var1=${var1:-default1}
  var2=${var2:-default2}
  # process this line
done < fileList
```

- `read -r var1 var2 dummy` - if a lines has more than two space separated tokens, they will be read into `dummy` and can be ignored
- if a lines has less than two tokens, the default values will be effective

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! Does this still apply if there are multiple lines?

Comment: Yes, you need to add the processing steps.

Comment: Where do I insert the steps for reading variable3 and variable4?

Comment: Each iteration of the loop will read one line from your file.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you meant by processing steps. So var1 and var2 will be overwritten in this loop, right?

Comment: the default assignment can be further reduced to `: ${var1:=default1}`

Comment: @user1378987 `var1` and `var2` will only be overwritten if they have no value or are null. Otherwise, they'll be set to the value of the line in the file. So actually, if they had no previous value, they're not really being overwritten; they're being assigned for the first time.

Comment: tried your suggestion but there are no values assigned to the variables. 

`$ while read -r var01 var02 var03 var04; do : ${var01:=default01}; : ${var02:=default02}; : ${var03:=default03}; : ${var04:=default04}; done < outF1.tmp`

Comment: How do I assign the values to var3 and var4 on the second line? The code does not read them

Answer (score 0):

## Script (file_reader.sh)

```
# Read in the 2 fields from the first (odd) line
while read var1 var2
do
  # Read in the 2 fields from the next (even) line
  read var3 var4

  # Set defaults
  : ${var1:=var1_default}
  : ${var2:=var2_default}
  : ${var3:=var3_default}
  : ${var4:=var4_default}

  echo "$var1 $var2 $var3 $var4"
done < foo.txt
```

## Input (foo.txt)

```
eins zwei         < line 1 (odd)
drei vier         < line 2 (even)
    < blank line
fünf
    < blank line
sechs sieben
acht
```

## Output

I piped the output of `file_reader.sh` into the `column` command to make the values more readable `$ ./file_reader.sh | columnt -t`…

```
eins         zwei         drei         vier
var1_default var2_default fünf         var4_default
var1_default var2_default sechs        sieben
acht         var2_default var3_default var4_default
```

Comment: Yes, that's also what I want to achieve however there should be multiple values for each line. And the default values will only apply to the blank line.